# Two functions seem equal but different in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to implement boolean without Prelude in Haskell.

When expression, `beq true true "TRUE" "FALSE"` is evaluated, it's okay. But when I try to evaluate `beq' true true "TRUE" "FALSE"`, it fails by some difference between expected type and actual type.

This is the code.

```hs
import qualified Prelude as P

i = \x -> x
k = \x y -> x
ki = k i

true = k
false = ki

not = \p -> p false true
beq = \p q -> p (q true false) (q false true)
beq' = \p q -> p q (not q)
```

So I checked inferred types of theses.

```
*Main> :type beq
beq
  :: (t1 -> t1 -> t2)
     -> ((p1 -> p1 -> p1) -> (p2 -> p2 -> p2) -> t1) -> t2

*Main> :type beq'
beq'
  :: (((p1 -> p2 -> p2) -> (p3 -> p4 -> p3) -> t1) -> t1 -> t2)
     -> ((p1 -> p2 -> p2) -> (p3 -> p4 -> p3) -> t1) -> t2
```

And it was not equal.

Here are the questions.

1. I thought it has the same type signature because `beq` and `beq'` seemingly make the same result when it folded and substituted. Like there are many ways to implement one function. But it wasn't. Are there some secret rules and syntax in Haskell?
2. If I want to write `beq` with the function `not`, how can I make it works?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think they should have the same types, since they have rather different implementations. Perhaps you should share which type you think GHCi has reported incorrectly, and what you think the type should be - together with your reasoning - then we can help to explain where you are mistaken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## How to fix the encoding

Church encodings work very well in an untyped calculus.

When types are added, things get more complicated. With simple types, for instance, the encodings are lost. With polymorphism they can be recovered, if higher ranks are supported. Note that type inference can't work well with higher types, so some explicit type annotation is needed.

For example, your `not` should be written as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
type ChBool = forall a. a -> a -> a

not :: ChBool -> ChBool
not f x y = f y x
```

It is important that boolean values are modeled as polymorphic functions, since otherwise they can only be used on a single type, making many examples fail. For instance, consider

```
foo :: Bool -> (Int, String)
foo b = (b 3 2, b "aa" "bb")
```

Here `b` needs to be used twice, once on `Int`s and once on `String`s. If `Bool` is not polymorphic this will fail.

## Why beta-reduction changes the inferred type

Further, you seem to be convinced that you can beta-reduce Haskell expressions and the inferred type before and after the reduction must be the same. That's not true, in general, as you discovered in your experiments. To see why, here's a simple example:

```
id1 x = x
```

The inferred type here is `id1 :: forall a. a -> a`, obviously. Consider instead this variant:

```
id2 x = (\ _ -> x) e
```

Note that `id2` beta-reduces to `id1`, *whatever `e` might be*. By choosing `e` carefully, though, we can restrict the type of `x`. E.g. let's choose `e = x "hello"`

```
id2 x = (\ _ -> x) (x "hello")
```

Now, the inferred type is `id2 :: forall b. (String -> b) -> String -> b` since `x` can only be a `String`-accepting function. It does not matter that `e` will not be evaluated, the type inference algorithm will make that well-typed anyway. This makes the inferred type of `id2` differ from the one of `id1`.